# How to correctly type vuex modules in vue 3 and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to figure out how to type vuex modules in a vue 3 typescript project. The official documentation is lacking in this area.

Assume I have a project like this:

```
import { createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store } from 'vuex';
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue';

interface FruitState  {
    apple: boolean,
    peach: boolean,
    plum: boolean
}

const FruitModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: (): FruitState => ({
      apple: true,
      peach: false,
      plum: true
    }),
    mutations: {},
    action: {}
}


export interface State {
    foo: string;
  }
  
  export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol();
  
  export const store = createStore<State>({
      modules: {
        fruit: fruitModule
      },
      state: {foo: 'foo'},
      mutations: { 
        changeFoo(state: State, payload: string){
            state.foo = payload
        }
      },
      actions: { 
        setFooToBar({commit}){
         commit('changeFoo', 'bar')
      }}
  })

  export function useStoreTyped() {
    return baseUseStore(key);
  }
```

... then later in a component:

```
  const apple = computed(() => store.state.fruit.apple);
```

When I try to access apple it does not work because it throws error
`Property 'fruit' does not exist on type 'State'`

Now IF I do something like this:

```
import { createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store } from 'vuex';
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue';

interface FruitState  {
    apple: boolean,
    peach: boolean,
    plum: boolean
}

const FruitModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: (): FruitState => ({
      apple: true,
      peach: false,
      plum: true,
    }),
    mutations: {},
    action: {}
}


export interface State {
    foo: string;
    fruit?: FruitState;
  }
  
  export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol();
  
  export const store = createStore<State>({
      modules: {
        fruit: fruitModule
      },
      state: {foo: 'foo'},
      mutations: { 
        changeFoo(state: State, payload: string){
            state.foo = payload
        }
      },
      actions: { 
        setFooToBar({commit}){
         commit('changeFoo', 'bar')
      }}
  })

  export function useStoreTyped() {
    return baseUseStore(key);
  }
```

And try again, the error changes to `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

It will allow me let me access the fruit module if I use the optional chaining `?.`

As in   `const apple = computed(() => store.state.fruit?.apple);`

But this doesn't seem acceptable to me since I know that fruit.apple is actually not undefined.

What's the correct way to include a module in your state types for vuex?

Comment: `fruit` is declared as optional in the `State` interface, so it's therefore possibly undefined, and it's access must always be checked. Making it optional implies that `store.state.fruit` might be (re)-assigned to `undefined` or `null` (e.g., in between calls). If you know `fruit` will *always* be defined, then don't make it optional in `State`. Why have you made it optional to begin with?

Comment: Vuex automatically places the `fruit` prop in the state object that is constructed from the  `createStore` function, this is what the `namespaced: true` option is for on the module. Making a fruit property on `State` interface was my attempt to let TS know that the module will eventually exist. And making it optional was so that I didn't have to include it in the initial top level state, because it is supposed to be set in the module.

Comment: It will exist immediately and not eventually, unless you use dynamic modules.

Comment: Sorry, maybe eventually wasn't the right term. But I mean it will exist once the createStore function is invoked.

Comment: IIRC I declared two separate types, for root state and the whole state with modules. useState should be used as a generic, and you may want to use the whole state in `useState<State>()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make the `fruit` state optional in the `State` interface:

```js
export interface State {
  foo: string;
  //fruit?: FruitState; 
  fruit: FruitState;
}
```

Based on your comment, you were trying to get around this TypeScript error when declaring the root state (as seen [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4KvN)):

```js
export const store = createStore<State>({
  modules: {
    fruit: fruitModule
  },
  state: { foo: 'foo' }, // ❌ Property 'fruit' is missing in type '{ foo: string; }' but required in type 'State'.
})
```

Use type assertion as a workaround:

```js
export const store = createStore<State>({
  modules: {
    fruit: fruitModule
  },
  state: { foo: 'foo' } as State, // ✅
})
```

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/WKVJGm)

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I'm wondering what a long term solution would be. Do you know whether the Vuex team is aware of this/working on it?